# Android: Unable to establish connection with Azure Service Bus Topics

Tags: xamarin.android, azureservicebus

On Android, I am unable to establish a connection with Azure Service Bus Topics.

**NOTE:**

```
1. I have observed this issue only on Android.

2. The same code works using a test project.

3. I have verified that the same connectionstring is being used in both scenarios.

4. I can execute web service calls from the Android client.
```

**Here's the code:**

```
let  client = ManagementClient(connectionstring)
let! found  = client.TopicExistsAsync(topicName) |> Async.AwaitTask // ERROR OCCURS HERE...
```

**Error Description:**

> Unable to resolve host "XXX.servicebus.windows.net": No
> address associated with hostname

Comment: Are you running the android on a device as compared to running a test on your computer? Assume the address can be accessed from a browser on phone?

Comment: I'm running an Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by performing the following actions:

1. Launched Android SDK Manager and Installed Google Play Services
2. Deleted my Android emulators and created new ones